# Cloud SQL creation with Deployment Manager - "Precondition check failed." error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-deployment-manager

I'm using the `gcp-types/sqladmin-v1beta4:instances` Resource Type to create a Cloud SQL instance using the Deployment Manager and I'm getting the error below:

```
{
  "ResourceType":"gcp-types/sqladmin-v1beta4:instances",
  "ResourceErrorCode":"400",
  "ResourceErrorMessage":{
    "code":400,
    "message":"Precondition check failed.",
    "status":"FAILED_PRECONDITION",
    "statusMessage":"Bad Request",
    "requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/[PROJECT_NAME]/instances",
    "httpMethod":"POST"
  }
}
```

Here's the configuration inside the `JINJA` file:

```
{% set deployment_name = env['deployment']  %}
{% set INSTANCE_NAME = deployment_name + '-instance'  %}

resources:
- name: {{ INSTANCE_NAME }}
  type: gcp-types/sqladmin-v1beta4:instances
  properties:
    region: us-central1
    rootPassword: root
    settings:
      tier: db-n1-standard-1
      backupConfiguration:
        binaryLogEnabled: true
        enabled: true

- name: demand_ml_db
  type: gcp-types/sqladmin-v1beta4:databases
  properties:
    name: demand_ml_db
    instance: $(ref.{{ INSTANCE_NAME }}.name)
    charset: utf8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FAILED_PRECONDITION` error - while not very descriptive, tends to be thrown when you're attempting to deploy over a previous Cloud SQL instance that was recently deleted; as a matter of fact, the instance you selected for deletion is not cleaned up instantly. There's an Issue Tracker thread regarding this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/145117807).

I was able to verify this on my end as well. The deployment using the `JINJA` file you've specified worked fine at first, but when I deleted it, and re-deployed - I received the same error.

The most simple approach is to try using a different deployment (or instance) name.